# Multiple interrupt vector tables for multiple processes

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling

My thoughts:

Suppose two applications are running in parallel in Linux x86 (multi-tasking), and they both share keyboard peripheral.  if I press a button on keyboard, interrupt occurs and control has to switch to corresponding interrupt routine. The starting  address of interrupt routine for an interrupt source  is obtained from Interrupt vector table which is already defined from  0x0000. But two applications may need different routines for the same keyboard interrupt. So the routine to be executed should depend on from which task it was actually interrupted.

So does this mean that two separate interrupt vector tables have to be kept for both processes and they are loaded by kernel while processes switch on time slices???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process running in a user address space can not service interrupts and thus does not have a vector table. The interrupt vector table will reside in the kernels address space.

In the case of a keyboard, the kernel's vector table(s) will handle the interrupt and pickup the key press. The kernel then will send the character from the key press to the user application via a system call. In linux, the system call will most likely be abstracted as a file being read by the user processes.

Multiple user processes (applications in this example) can read from the same file, so the behavior depends on the specifics of the file/file like device. There is a good chance it will end up being an unpredictable race between processes to read the data first. In practice, its often a bad idea to have multiple processes concurrently accessing the same file.

Comment: I am not convinced. Are you saying that all the user processes running in parallel can have only one common interrupt routine for all external interrupts like keyboard etc? But it makes sense that different tasks may need different services for the same interrupt. For eg: clicking a button on keyboard should do something for process A, but I want to do something else for process B for the same button.

Comment: @MeenieLeis "Interrupts" are not something that is visible to processes at all. If a process wants to listen for keyboard strokes, it must ask the kernel to do it. The kernel handles interrupts, and if it sees that a process is waiting for the keyboard, it passes the key stroke to that process when it handles the interrupt. Unix has concepts like sessions and foreground processes to manage multiple processes listening for keyboard strokes.

Comment: @root Will the task remain blocked until the stroke occurs? Is it like -  kernel Pass a message to the process that a key stroke occurred and this is that key?

Comment: Almost. The process typically reads from a file which represents keyboard input (typically TTY, e.g. `/dev/pts/2`). if no keystroke is pending, the read-from-file call will put the process into blocked state. once a keystroke is handled, it's pushed to the file, and the kernel puts the process waiting for the read call to complete into runnable mode.